# Use own menu bar in customized Cordova InAppBrowser Plugin

Tags: ios, cordova, ipad, inappbrowser, cordova-ios

I have a Cordova iOS app that uses the Cordova InAppBrowser plugin. The InAppBrowser has been modified natively so that a menu bar is displayed as a header above the InAppBrowser, so that various other functionalities can be used (e.g. a drawing/screenshot function). To fulfill this requirement, the InAppBrowser plugin was forked and adapted: In addition to the standard parameters of the InAppBrowser plugin you can add offsets to our customized InAppBrowser to avoid filling the whole display and to have the possibility to show the above mentioned menu bar in the empty area.

This worked successfully for years with the following versions:

- Cordova: 6.5.0
- Cordova-iOS: 4.5.2
- InAppBrowser Plugin: 1.6.1

After upgrading to the latest Cordova Framework we currently have the following versions in use:

- Cordova: 10.0.0
- Cordova-iOS: 6.1.1
- InAppBrowser Plugin: 4.0.0

The InAppBrowser Plugin is forked in the same way as the old version, so that a menu bar can be displayed at the top. This seems to work optically correct respectively as before. But if you click on our navigation bar now, it doesn't react. So it looks like the plugin or the WkWebView makes an invisible glass pane over the navigation bar. You don't see this "glass pane" in the DOM elements, so it is likely that this happens somehow natively. For example, if you make a URL with "toolbar=yes", you have the possibility to close the InAppBrowser and only then, you have access to the navigation bar behind it and you can use the menu elements. There are also several parameters in the InAppBrowser plugin, which can be passed when opening a URL (e.g. PresentationStyle), but they don't have any effect.

Who had this problem and could solve it? How?